# How to execute a script in shell when a shortcut key is pressed

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome-terminal

How could I execute a script in Shell when a shortcut key is pressed.

Essentially what I need is when a shortcut key is pressed the script should read from a file and display that content in the terminal.

Comment: I tried the method you used `bind '"\e[24~":"airmon-ng start wlan0\n"'` but after I closed the terminal, the thing seems to be reset and all the hotkeys are gone

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use the builtin command, `bind` to map a keyboard shortcut so that it executes a command/shell script.

#### Example

Say we want to run the command, `pwd`, when we press the <kbd>F12</kbd> key.

```
$ bind '"\e[24~":"pwd\n"'
```

Now when I press <kbd>F12</kbd> at my prompt, `$`:

```
$ pwd
/home/saml
```

#### Determining keyboard shortcuts

You can use the following technique to determine the escape code for a given keyboard shortcut. On most systems press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>, release, and then press the key you want the code for. There are some other systems it will work with <kbd>M</kbd> instead of <kbd>V</kbd>

#### Example

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> then release both <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>V</kbd> and finally press  <kbd>F12</kbd> in a terminal window returns this:

```
$ ^[[24~
```

This output can be interpreted as follows, `^[` is the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key. So when we want to specify this particular key using the `bind` command we need to use a `\e` to denote the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key followed by everything else from above. So the `bind` command looks like this:

```
$ bind '"\e[24~":"....."'
```

#### Executing a command in the middle

You can also make use of `bind -x` to setup keyboard shortcuts that will run commands while you're in the middle of typing something at the prompt, and these commands' output will be displayed, but what ever you were typing at the prompt will remain intact.

```
$ bind -x '"\eW":"..."'
```

**NOTE:** This method only works with keyboard shortcuts that output 1 character, so <kbd>F12</kbd> won't work here.

#### Example

Let's alias the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>.

```
$ bind -x '"\eW":"who"'
```

Say I'm typing the command `finger`:

```
$ finger
```

Now I hit the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>:

```
saml     tty1         2013-09-01 11:01 (:0)
saml     pts/0        2013-09-01 11:03 (:0.0)
saml     pts/1        2013-09-01 11:05 (:0.0)
saml     pts/2        2013-09-01 11:05 (:0.0)
saml     pts/5        2013-09-03 22:45 (:0.0)
$ finger
```

What's going on is `bind` is running the command defined, `who`, taking its output and inserting it in front of the prompt. If you repeat it you'll see what's going on, here's output from me hitting it 2 times:

```
saml     tty1         2013-09-01 11:01 (:0)
saml     pts/0        2013-09-01 11:03 (:0.0)
saml     pts/1        2013-09-01 11:05 (:0.0)
saml     pts/2        2013-09-01 11:05 (:0.0)
saml     pts/5        2013-09-03 22:45 (:0.0)
saml     tty1         2013-09-01 11:01 (:0)
saml     pts/0        2013-09-01 11:03 (:0.0)
saml     pts/1        2013-09-01 11:05 (:0.0)
saml     pts/2        2013-09-01 11:05 (:0.0)
saml     pts/5        2013-09-03 22:45 (:0.0)
$ finger
```

#### Your problem

So one idea would be to use the `bind -x` method above and `cat` to display this text file at your prompt:

```
$ bind -x '"\eW":"cat someinfo.txt"'
```

Now when I run commands I can see this file like so:

```
This is text from some 
multi-line file reminding
me how to do some 
stuff
$ finger
```

The output of file `someinfo.txt` is being displayed above my `finger` command above.

#### References

- [In bash, how do I bind a function key to a command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200800/in-bash-how-do-i-bind-a-function-key-to-a-command)

Comment: I need only to display the contents, not to execute it.

Comment: So bind to a script that displays the contents.

Comment: Ctrl+m is not working for me. It acts as if I just pressed enter. An alternative I *think* (I'm a bash newbie) is to type `echo ' ` (space after the single-quote), then press Ctrl+v, then the key you want, and then space, single-quote...as described [here](http://superuser.com/a/589629/313690). Example: `echo ' ^[OD '`

Comment: Can I apply these by using `bindkey`?