# Start command and stop command in terminal on keyboard (hotkey) shortcut press?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, process-management

I have seen [How to execute a script in shell when a shortcut key is pressed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89622/how-to-execute-a-script-in-shell-when-a-shortcut-key-is-pressed), but that is not what I want.

If you have used `recordmydesktop`, you may have noticed the following in its manual:

> After startup, it can be controled only through the following signals:
>   SIGUSR1  causes  the  program to pause if it's currently recording, and
>   vice-versa.
>   SIGTERM causes normal termination of the recording. [...]
>   See  --pause-shortcut  and  --stop-shortcut  , on the Misc.  section of
>   Options bellow. [...]
>   --pause-shortcut MOD+KEY
>       Shortcut that will be used for pausing  or  unpausing
>       the recording. [...]
>       Default  is  Control+Mod1+p (Mod1 usually corresponds
>       to left Alt). [...]
>   --stop-shortcut MOD+KEY
>       Shortcut that will be used to stop the recording.
>       For more, see -pause-shortcut above.
>       Default is Control+Mod1+s.

Well, I'd like the same - but for an arbitrary, typically long-running, terminal program. Say I want to use `ffmpeg`; then I'd want to use an application somewhat in this way (pseudocode);

```
$ myKeyListenerApp --start-shortcut Control+Mod1+p --stop-shortcut Control+Mod1+s ffmpeg -i mybigmovie.avi -r 24 mybigmovie.ogv
```

The trick would be that `myKeyListenerApp` would start `ffmpeg` "paused" (or simply not start it at all); then as soon as it is notified of the start shortcut press, it would start `ffmpeg` and let it do it's thing. Then when I press the stop shortcut, `ffmpeg` would either pause, or if that is not possible, then simply be killed, upon which `myKeyListenerApp` would exit, too.

Does an application like this exist?